# How can you create a single-value sequence?

Tags: oracle, sequence

On the prod environment, we have a huge sequence in a field (by now, 13 digits).
On the dev environment, we want to ignore this sequence.
Is there any way to create a sequence that always returns the same value?

I mean, to get something like this:

```
select my_seq.CURRVAL from dual; --> E.G: 5
select my_seq.NEXTVAL from dual; --> E.G: 5
```

I've tried setting the increment to 0, setting the min_value equal to max_value, but nothing works.
Thank you.

[Edited]--> Oracle 12c, and need to be the same value always. Sorry about the 1-2-1-2 sequences, they don't match our needs.

Comment: If you want to ignore it, then why does the value it returns matter? Just create a regular sequence and ignore the value

Comment: I remember some problems with the sequences during load tests using RAT (real application testing) and HP Loadrunner. As far as I remember developers had to rewrite some parts of functional tests to avoid dependencies on sequences. They didn't change sequences definitions, but they reset them to pre-tests values at start

Comment: This sequence is part of an audit value. In prod, it is useful, but in other environments, we process records twice, and want to check if there are any other differences, apart from this sequence.

Comment: Isn't it a strange wish ? You have not told the complete story. What you mean by ignore ? What benefit you get from it ?

Comment: we make "dual processing": With and without our changes. If we have the same value in the fields, most records should be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single-value sequence can be created with an unsupported and potentially dangerous manual change to the data dictionary. Only use this solution as a last resort, never run it on production, test it thoroughly on a sandbox database before even running it on dev, and document the change so future developers can understand why this was done.

You can't directly create the sequence you want so you must first create a sequence that is pretty close - the initial sequence starts at 5, increments by 1, and cycles between 4 and 5. After a valid sequence is created, update `SYS.SEQ$.MINVALUE` to create a sequence that cycles back to the same number each time. Finally, you must commit and immediately restart the database before using the sequence. (I'm not sure why, but if you don't restart, Oracle will change `SYS.SEQ$.MINVALUE` back to a legal value as soon as you use the sequence.)

```
SYS@orclpdb> create sequence jheller.my_seq start with 5 increment by 1 minvalue 4 maxvalue 5 cycle nocache;

Sequence created.

SYS@orclpdb> update sys.seq$ set minvalue = 5 where obj# = (select object_id from dba_objects where object_name = 'MY_SEQ' and owner = 'JHELLER');

1 row updated.

SYS@orclpdb> commit;

Commit complete.

SYS@orclpdb> shutdown immediate
Pluggable Database closed.
SYS@orclpdb> startup
Pluggable Database opened.
SYS@orclpdb> select jheller.my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         5

SYS@orclpdb> select jheller.my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         5
```

The above code works for me on 19c with the multitenant option. The sequences don't use any fancy new features, so I think the code should work for much older versions of Oracle. But since this is an unsupported change I can't make any promises.

### Other ideas that didn't work (but maybe they will motivate someone to find a better solution)

You can't directly create a sequence that does not increment at all - that generates the error "ORA-04002: INCREMENT must be a non-zero integer". You also can't create a sequence that directly cycles back to the minimum value, that generates the error "ORA-04005: INCREMENT must be less than MAXVALUE  minus MINVALUE".

Overlapping-name tricks don't work either. While it is valid to create a package named MY_SEQ with functions named CURRVAL and NEXTVAL, the parser will still expect a sequence when it see the expression `MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL`. The same problem also applies to creating a user named MY_SEQ with two functions for CURRVAL and NEXTVAL.

Comment: Thank you very much. That should work, but I guess it can be reverted any time by the Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

Not the same value, but only 1 and 2:

```sql
SQL> create sequence my_seq START WITH 1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 2 cycle session nocache;

Sequence created.

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual connect by level<=5;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
         2
         1
         2
         1
```

*NB*: `session` sequences require Oracle >=12.1

Comment: Sorry, this solution is not useful for us.

Comment: @Jose ok, so the only way for you is to `alter sequence` after each run: either change `increment by` between 1 and -1 each time, or change `start with`

Answer (score -1):

This works in 10g, 11g, 12c (don't have other versions to try it, but I presume that it should be fine).

```
SQL> create sequence my_seq minvalue 0 maxvalue 1 nocache cycle;

Sequence created.

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         0

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         0

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Though, as @a_horse commented, why bother at all?

Comment: `session` sequences are much faster since they have no concurrency between sessions, that's why I suggest to use them on 12+

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP didn't mention which version they use, @Sayan. I still agree with a_horse that this is more or less pointless.

Comment: I remember some problems with the sequences during load tests using RAT (real application testing) and HP Loadrunner. As far as I remember developers had to rewrite some parts of functional tests to avoid dependencies on sequences. They didn't change sequences definitions, but they reset them to pre-tests values at start

Comment: Sorry, this solution is not useful for us.

Comment: Don't worry, it is you who have a problem. Though, you might not be able to solve it as simple as you'd want. Good luck anyway!